# How to parse an HTML file with QT?

Tags: html, c++, qt

The goal is to achieve a `QDomDocument` or something similar with the content of an HTML (not XML) document.

The problem is that some tags, especially `script` trigger errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = [1,2,3];
        var b = (2<a.length);
    </script>
</head>
<body/>
</html>
```

> Not well formed: Element type "a.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

I understand that HTML is not the same as XML, but it seems reasonable that Qt has a solution for this:

- Setting the parser to accept HTML
- Another class for HTML
- A way to set some tags name as CDATA.

My current try only achieves normal XML parsing:

```
QString mainHtml;

{
    QFile file("main.html");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) qDebug() << "Error reading file main.html";
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    mainHtml = stream.readAll();
    file.close();
}

QQDomDocument doc;
QString errStr;
int errLine=0, errCol=0;
doc.setContent( mainHtml, false, &errStr, &errLine, &errCol);
if (!errStr.isEmpty())
{
    qDebug() << errStr << "L:" << errLine << ":" << errCol;
}

std::function<void(const QDomElement&, int)> printTags=
[&printTags](const QDomElement& elem, int tab)
{
    QString space(3*tab, ' ');
    QDomNode n = elem.firstChild();
    for( ;!n.isNull(); n=n.nextSibling()) 
    {
        QDomElement e = n.toElement();
        if(e.isNull()) continue;
        
        qDebug() << space + e.tagName(); 
        printTags( e, tab+1);
    }
};
printTags(doc.documentElement(), 0);
```

Note: I would like to avoid including the full webkit for this.

Comment: You do have the option to convert HTML into XHTML with various third party libraries, which can then be parsed using Qt's XML parsers. But do pay attention to the manual, specifically the part about not using [QDomDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html) in modern Qt code.

Comment: `specifically the part about not using QDomDocument in modern Qt code` Uhhgg, nice detail!

Comment: Here's one thirdparty library which can help with converting HTML to XML: [tidy-html5](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5). Used it myself for the very same goal, works yet not without a few glitches; [here](https://github.com/d1vanov/libquentier/blob/master/src/enml/HTMLCleaner.cpp) is an example of its usage in a Qt project, just in case.

Comment: I see the way, thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use [htmlcxx](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/). It is licensed under LPGL. It works on Linux and Windows. If you use windows compile with [msys.](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys)

To compile it just extract the files and run

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/htmlcxx
make
make install
```

In your .pro file add the include and library directory.

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/htmlcxx/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/htmlcxx/lib -lhtmlcxx
```

**Usage example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "htmlcxx/html/ParserDom.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  using namespace std;
  using namespace htmlcxx;

  //Parse some html code
  string html = "<html><body>hey<A href=\"www.bbxyard.com\">myhome</A></body></html>";
  HTML::ParserDom parser;
  tree<HTML::Node> dom = parser.parseTree(html);
  //Print whole DOM tree
  cout << dom << endl;

  //Dump all links in the tree
  tree<HTML::Node>::iterator it = dom.begin();
  tree<HTML::Node>::iterator end = dom.end();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
  {
     if (strcasecmp(it->tagName().c_str(), "A") == 0)
     {
       it->parseAttributes();
       cout << it->attribute("href").second << endl;
     }
  }

  //Dump all text of the document
  it = dom.begin();
  end = dom.end();
  for (; it != end; ++it)
  {
    if ((!it->isTag()) && (!it->isComment()))
    {
      cout << it->text() << " ";
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Credits for the example: 
https://github.com/bbxyard/sdk/blob/master/examples/htmlcxx/htmlcxx-demo.cpp

You can't use an XML parser for HTML. You either use htmlcxx or convert the HTML to valid XML. Then you are free to use QDomDocument, Qt XML parsers, etc.

QWebEngine has also parsing functionality, but brings a large overhead with the application.

Comment: I think your "Dump all links in the tree" can be much simpler:

`    for (auto it: dom)
    {
     if (it.tagName()=="A")
     {
      it.parseAttributes();
      cout << it.attribute("href").second << endl;
     }
    }`

Comment: @Adrian Maire thanks for the information. I have not written the example code. I have added the github link below the code example for credits. Anyway, I can confirm htmlcxx works fine in my Qt project. I crawl huge sites and parse some attributes.